# How to find and remove an anonymous object in one of 7 SortedLists in a List?

Tags: c#, list, anonymous

The Item could be in any of the Lists. But every Item only once. There shouldn't be the same (or similar) item in one of the other lists.

Here is my class.

```
class Calendar
{
    public List<SortedList<string, Item>> list;

    public Item()
    {
        list = new List<SortedList<string, Item>>(); //List of Week
        list.Add(new SortedList<string, Item>()); //Monday
        list.Add(new SortedList<string, Item>()); //Tuesday
        list.Add(new SortedList<string, Item>()); //Wednesday
        list.Add(new SortedList<string, Item>()); //Thursday
        list.Add(new SortedList<string, Item>()); //Friday
        list.Add(new SortedList<string, Item>()); //Saturday
        list.Add(new SortedList<string, Item>()); //Sunday
    }
}
```

To remove an Item i tried something like this:

```
public void RemoveItem(string key)
{
    foreach (SortedList<string, Item> item in list)
    {
        if (item.Keys.Contains(key))
        {
            item.Remove(key);
        }
    }
}
```

but that apparently does not work.

Here is how I add the Items. But that should be obvious:

```
public void AddItem(string Day, Item i)
    {
        string s = i.Title
        switch (Tag)
        {
            case "Monday":
                list[0].Add(s, i);
                break;
            case "Tuesday":
                list[1].Add(s, i);
                break;
            case "Wednesday":
                list[2].Add(s, i);
                break;
            case "Thursday":
                list[3].Add(s, i);
                break;
            case "Friday":
                list[4].Add(s, i);
                break;
            case "Saturday":
                list[5].Add(s, i);
                break;
            case "Sunday":
                list[6].Add(s, i);
                break;
            default:
                list[0].Add(s, i);
                break;
        }
    }
```

At first I used `List<List<Item>>` but I figured out that a SortedList is easier to handle for my purposes.

Comment: Have you tried using a for loop instead?

Comment: yes. did not work either.

Comment: I don't see that you are enumerating the second list, `foreach(var list in lists){ list.RemoveWhere(x => x.key == key);}` as an example...

Comment: It seems like I don't have (access to) the method `.RemoveWhere()`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are removing from the SortedKey not the List. I interpreted your intention is to remove the SortedList from the List, if that is your intention, one way to do would be:

```
        private void GoHere()
        {
            var list = new List<SortedList<string, string>>(); //List of Week
            list.Add(new SortedList<string, string>() {{"monday", "monday"}}); //Monday
            list.Add(new SortedList<string, string>() {{"tues", "monday"}}); //Tuesday
            list.Add(new SortedList<string, string>() {{"wed", "monday"}}); //Wednesday
            list.Add(new SortedList<string, string>() {{"thurs", "monday"}}); //Thursday
            list.Add(new SortedList<string, string>() {{"fri", "monday"}}); //Friday
            list.Add(new SortedList<string, string>() {{"sun", "monday"}}); //Saturday
            int? index = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                SortedList<string, string> sortedList = list[i];
                if (sortedList.ContainsKey("wed"))
                {
                    index = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (index.HasValue)
            {
                list.RemoveAt(index.Value);
            }
        }
```

Comment: My intention is to remove one Item that is inside one of the SortedLists. But first (because I don't know in wich SortedList it is inside) I need to find the Item.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I figured out the solution.
There was no problem with my logic.

The string I used to find and delete the Item came from this:

```
string[] seperators = { "|" };
string[] s = "Name | Title".Split(seperators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
Calendar.RemoveItem(s[1]);
```

but apperently a space was kept before the string. So i added this code and now it works:

```
string title = s[2].Remove(0, 1);
Calendar.RemoveItem(title);
```

Comment: Sidenote: `myString.Trim()` will automatically remove all whitespace characters and newlines both at the start and end of the string (but not in the middle). There is also a `TrimStart()` and `.TrimEnd()` if you only want to trim one side of the string.